# Firebird Error: "operating system directive CreateFile failed"

Tags: sql, database, firebird, firebird2.1

Did any one see this error ??

I'm using Firebird 2.1 and database create statement is getting failed on v.first stored procedure execution.

Error Message:

```
[869] : There was a problem creating a DBProvider with the following parameters: StoredProcedureName:sel_NextObjectID
 2. operating system directive CreateFile failed
 3. operating system directive CreateFile failed
    Stack Trace 


 2.at FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient.FbConnectionInternal.Connect()
   at FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient.FbConnectionPool.Create()
   at FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient.FbConnectionPool.CheckOut()
   at FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient.FbConnection.Open()
   at FirebirdDBProvider.NewProvider_Internal(String commandText, String connectionString, CommandType commandType)  

3 at FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient.FbConnectionInternal.Connect()
   at FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient.FbConnectionPool.Create()
   at FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient.FbConnectionPool.CheckOut()
   at FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient.FbConnection.Open()
   at FirebirdDBProvider.NewProvider_Internal(String commandText, String connectionString, CommandType commandType)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, deleting all temp file fixed this thing. Found the same issue on firebird too.

1)  Make sure your application (on which you're facing this issue) is not running.
2)  One Run dialog (Window + R) and type in “%temp%” and click “ok”
3)  In the opened folder delete all the files (which can be deleted).
4)  Start the application.

Answer (score 1):

Just had same issue, the reason was no free space available on the system drive.

Answer (score 0):

You can get this error when you are attempting to connect to a database which does not yet exist.

It is not entirely clear from your post what you mean with 'database create statement is getting failed on v.first stored procedure execution', but I assume you are attempting to create a database and then execute DDL.

To connect to a database, you first need to create it. To create a database you need to use [createDatabase](http://web.firebirdsql.org/dotnetfirebird/blog/2005/01/creating-database-programmatically.html) first.